# fastapi cookie update in middleware delay in getting a result

Tags: python, fastapi

There is middleware that checks if the database has information about the received notification and if it does, it adds a flag to the response cookie, and if it exists, the notification will be displayed in the html template.

**middleware.py**

```
async def get_user_notifications(request: Request, call_next):
    response = await call_next(request)
    if await is_authenticated(request):
        user = await get_current_user(request)
        if user['is_notified']:
            notifications = await MessagesService.get_count(int(user['user_id']))
            if notifications:
                # add notification to response
                response.set_cookie(
                    key="user_notifications",
                    value=notifications['total'],
                    httponly=True,
                ) if notifications['total'] else None
    return response
```

**main.py**

```
app.middleware('http')(get_user_notifications)
```

**html**

```
{% if request.cookies.user_notifications %}
    <small class="notification-badge">{{request.cookies.user_notifications}}</small>
{% else %}
    <small class="notification-badge-empty">0</small>
{% endif %}
```

All the logic works, but the notification is not displayed the first time the page is refreshed, but the second time. I.e. if the database has information about an incoming notification, the user has to refresh the page twice to see it.
What is the reason for this behaviour and how can I make the information appear after the first refresh of the html page?

Comment: You're transferring control to the next part of the request chain first: `response = await call_next(request)` - then when the response gets back, you set the cookie. Your template has no way of knowing that this cookie has been set, since it's not set before _after_ a response gets returned the first time?

Comment: Hmm, can't find a way to pass the parameter before call `response = await call_next(request)`. Without definition of `response` I can't call `response.set_cookie`. How can this be done?

Comment: Use `request.state` to attach state to the current request instead of attaching it to a cookie, possibly? Not sure if you even need to get cookies involved here?

Comment: Using `request.state` might be good idea. Try this now.

Comment: @MatsLindh Yes it works. thanks for advice. maybe you know how to remove the key from the `request.state` ?

Comment: [According to the implementation of State](https://github.com/encode/starlette/blob/4b37cf89ec80f8eee74eefa8bdce6384ae7af5c3/starlette/datastructures.py#L680) it implements `__delattr__`, so `del request.state.name_of_field` should work.